# VS 2013 - how to track file changes in solution explorer?

Tags: git, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I'm using git from the command line (cygwin). When I checkout older commits or change branches, the solution explorer doesn't update to match the new files that have been created/deleted. How can I make visual studio refresh to reflect the file changes?

I have the settings "Detect when file is changed outside the environment" and "Auto-load changes, if saved" enabled, but they don't seem to help. The button "show all files" will show files that were introduced but doesn't remove files that are now gone.

Comment: What's the latest service pack you have installed for VS2013?

Comment: It says it's on update 4, which seems to be the newest one

Comment: Apparently there is an open defect against the described behavior which wasn't fixed yet... 
https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/773039/detect-file-changes-outside-environment-not-working

Comment: Can you please provide more details about your setup?  Do you have some junction points or symlinks like in the bug report that @DeJaVo pointed to?

Comment: I'm using windows 7 64 bit, and a new install of Visual Studio Community 2013. I have Python Tools for Visual Studio installed, and that's it as far as extensions go.


The bug report doesn't quite describe my problem. For me, let's say I have branch 1 with file A. Then branch 2 deletes file A and adds file B. When I switch between branches, solution explorer shows that file A has gone bad and doesn't show anything about file B.


I've since started using visual studio's built-in git tools which solves my problem, but the concern in my post still stands.

Answer (score 1):

As I noted in my comment there is an open defect against the behavior you would like to achieve.

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/773039/detect-file-changes-outside-environment-not-working

**Update**: First option:

In the meantime , try to install a vs2013 extension to handle it.

I recommend 2 extension that may help you:

1. [Git Source Control Provider](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/63a7e40d-4d71-4fbb-a23b-d262124b8f4c)
2. [Workspace Reloader](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/6705affd-ca37-4445-9693-f3d680c92f38)

I hope it will address your need.

**Update**: the second option is to use vs2013 integrated git tools

Comment: Thank you for your help. I've decided to use visual studio's built-in git tools for version control, which alleviates the problem.

Comment: That was my second option I wanted to offer but I inferred from your question this is not what you want. Anyhow,show your appreciation and respect my effort with vote up :)

Comment: Thanks for voting up, for giving the complete answer I add the info from you comment to my answer , so other that will be interested in the same manner will have the info.